# Making a hierarchy with case classes in Scala

Tags: json, scala, hierarchy, json-deserialization, case-class

I have 2 types of documents: PDFDocument and XMLDocument. Both are case classes (I need matching them). 
Now, I need to have a collection of documents. So, I created PrivateDocument to make a hierarchy. 
These documents I get it from a request to an external server, so I'd like to validate de response of that request:

```
response.json.validate[List[ProformaDocument]]
```

The problem is that, if PrivateDocument is a case class, then case-to-case inheritance is prohibited.
If PrivateDocument is a trait or a class, then I can't deserialize the JSON, because the trait don't have a Reads.

After all of that, I need to return the List to the web page that ask it. So, again, I need to transform the List into a Json array.

What can I do in this cases to make a correct hierarchy and also manage the case class / Json transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You can still perform matches on ordinary classes.

While case-to-case inheritance doesn't work, you can make an ordinary abstract base class and have case classes inherit from it.

Comment: It's the same. With that this is what happens:

No Json deserializer found for type List[model.PrivateDocument]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

Comment: Try it the other way then. Don't use case classes. Case classes offer the benefit of auto-created constructors, equals and hashes, but sometimes we can't afford that.